# Возврат к списку, ссылка из детального просмотра новости, Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

По нажатию на ссылку "Возврат к списку", редирект идет на первую страницу.

Если у меня записей достаточно много, то если я просмотрел новость на 10 странице, и нажму "Возврат", то вернусь на первую.

Где изменить параметр ссылки так, чтобы он возвращал на ту страницу, на которую нужно?

Answer (score 0):

Мало ли кому пригодится:

В настройках компонента news включаем "Включить эмуляцию навигации браузера";

На саму ссылку "Возврат к списку" вешаем javascript:history.back()